# Is ride-hailing the same as hail and ride?

Tags: vocabulary

I am not a native English speaker. I need some experience straight from the horse's mouth. 
Today I read an article with the word '[ride-hailing](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/apr/12/why-everyone-hates-uber-seven-step-playbook?CMP=fb_gu)' (and I posted a quote below this paragraph).
I got curious what ride-hailing is, so I opened my dictionary and tried to translate the word into my language. There have been no answers. There seem to be no equivalents in my language. I decided to add this word to a user-contributed dictionary. But, first, I need to understand the idea behind the word. This might help find a similar word in my language. So, I needed to understand what 'ride-hailing' was, and I googled it. 
I have found no reliable sources to explain *the word*. However, there was a big Wikipedia article on ... **[hail and ride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_and_ride)!** The other serious-looking results were mostly about ... '**[ride-hailing](https://blancride.com/blog/ride-hailing-vs-ride-sharing-whats-the-difference/)**' and [there is](http://www.yourdictionary.com/ride-hailing-service) even an online dictionary article. Suddenly, I got an idea, an insight. What if both words - *hail and ride* and  *ride-hailing* are the same thing simply written in different words? 
In this case, if the connotations - the words - are the same, than *ride-hailing* means *hail and ride* and, so I can continue with my little research.
**THE QUESTION IS: are *ride-hailing* and *hail and ride* the same thing?**

**HERE IS THE [QUOTE from TheGuardian](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/apr/12/why-everyone-hates-uber-seven-step-playbook) with the original words:**

> "Uber tripled federal lobbying efforts in 2016, spending $1.36m – a
>   whopping $890,000 more than in 2015. These efforts focused on
>   modernizing existing laws, including pushing to allow federal
>   employees to use 
>   ***ride-hailing***
>   services when traveling on official
>   business."

So, here they are talking about taxis, and not buses!

---

But, then, [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_and_ride) talks buses:

> In public transport in the United Kingdom and Australia, hail and ride
>   is boarding or alighting a mode of public transport by signalling the
>   driver or conductor that one wishes to board or alight, rather than
>   the more conventional system of using a designated stop. Hail and ride
>   is used primarily in bus transport.

Please, help me with your expertise. I understand you can speak different versions of English, so, it would be useful if you mentioned your part of the world.

P.S. The images in this article were borrowed from [Business Standard](http://bsmedia.business-standard.com/_media/bs/img/article/2016-12/19/full/1482144889-9375.jpg) and [Transport for London](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20120816055846/http://www.tfl.gov.uk/assets/downloads/corporate/new-route-324.pdf). Also, I got puzzled by the Google image search results where ride-hailing was mainly about taxi, while hail and ride was about both buses and taxis.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried translating "hail a ride"?  Could you then create "ride-hailing" in your language?  (In American English "hail a tax" or "hail a ride" is common; I'm not familiar with hailing a bus in AmE, but in fact we do it.)

Comment: *ride-hailing* means *hailing a ride*. It is only the *hailing* part of *hand and ride*. After hailing a ride (taxi, etc.) you might choose not to actually ride.

Answer (score 1):

**Ride-hailing** is the *act* of stopping a vehicle to ride it. **Hail-and-ride** is the *system* (scheme, set of practices and rules) in which buses can be / must be hailed by passengers who want to ride. Hail-and-ride is used to distinguish such systems within modes of transportation (buses) where it is not customary.

Comment: Hello, Paul Richter. Thank you for your contribution. However I could not understand your last sentence. Perhaps, there must be FROM instead of within? Could you paraphrase it to make it clear, please?



 `Hail-and-ride is used to distinguish such systems within modes of  transportation (buses) where it is not customary.`

Comment: Most bus systems have stops. But there are some which require hailing, and those are called hail-and-ride.

Comment: I intended to say that a "mode of transportation" would refer to all bus systems, of which most have stops, but within that group, some would be hail-and-ride. But I can see where "from" would also work, if "modes... where it is not customary" refers to stop-based bus systems, from which we would distinguish hail-and-ride systems